# How can I enable a constexpr `missing return statement` active error without warnings?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

Suppose I have `constexpr` data set. I mostly use it at compile time, it stores data for settings that can affect future `constexpr` statements. The `string_view` allows me to name these settings and search for them easily:

```cpp
struct data {
    std::string_view name;
    int value;
};

constexpr auto data_set = std::array{
    data{"foo", 100},
    data{"bar", 200},
};
```

and this is the `constexpr` function that allows me to find data points and return their value:

```
constexpr int get_data(std::string_view search) {
    for (auto& data : data_set) {
        if (data.name == search) {
            return data.value;
        }
    }
}
```

this works nicely, when I call this function with correct string names and incorrect ones. Because if it doesn't find `name`, the function has no return statement and therefore fails to initialize a `constexpr` value:

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr auto foo = get_data("foo");
    constexpr auto foo2 = get_data("foo2"); //Error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
}
```

and my IDE (Visual Studio) even gives me a nice visible active error:

```
Error (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value
```

however, while using this and having non-constexpr calls to it, I always get the warning

```
warning C4715: 'get_data': not all control paths return a value
```

and obviously I can't add a default return value, as that defeats the "`constexpr` fails, if invalid" purpose, but I still would like to be able to initialize run time variables with it (as the search string_view is still known at compile time making this safe).

---

So is there a way to keep this error for invalid inputs, but remove the error? And can you also make this work for functions that return nothing?

Comment: Return std::optional or throw an exception when nothing was found. Note: constexpr doesn't ensure the code is evaluated at compile time. If the compiler feels like it it can run it at runtime and then any invalid string would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow std::optional won't give me an active error, but throwing an exception enables this behaviour. (as it can't initialize the constexpr, and they removed warning for no return if there is a throw instead). Thanks!

Comment: You would extract the value from an optional with `std::optional<T>::value`, which throws `std::bad_optional_access` when it contains no value and that would give you the error. It's basically the same as you throwing the exception except the interface clearly shows the function may not return a result while with the exception the interface won't show it.

Comment: I like your philosophy here, code that describes itself. I think for a simple search a simple throw is enough, but for more complicated cases, like with many branches, this is a very clean solution.

Comment: You should read https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines for lots more good practices. Although I believe using `std::optional` over a NotFound exception because then code documents itself isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

[`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) will enable this behaviour. It makes it so, that any function marked this way, has to be evaluated at compile time. This will also remove the warning, as it will be replaced by an error if it didn't evaluate properly.

```
consteval int get_data(std::string_view search) {
    for (auto& data : data_set) {
        if (data.name == search) {
            return data.value;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    constexpr auto foo = get_data("foo");
    constexpr auto foo2 = get_data("foo2");
}
```

the `"foo2"` line results in C2131 and active error E3133:

```
Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant
Error (active)  E3133   call to consteval function "get_data" did not produce a valid constant expression
```

you can still use this to initialize run-time variables:

```cpp
auto bar = get_data("bar");
```

as `get_data` can be evaluated at compile time, and is basically replaced by `data{ "bar", 200 }.value;`, or just `200`.

---

now `consteval` will make it so that that pure runtime calls no longer work (like reading the search term from `std::cin` input or from a file) but that is desired behavior, as that could theoretically result in the unspecified branch if the input is invalid.

---

> can you also make this work for functions that return nothing?

it is possible to add statements that are invalid in the branch that is supposed to fail, if reached. For example `1 / 0`:

```cpp
consteval void check_data(std::string_view search) {
    for (auto& data : data_set) {
        if (data.name == search) {
            return;
        }
    }
    auto invalid = 1 / 0;
}

int main() {
    check_data("foo");
    check_data("bar");
    check_data("bar2"); //E3133 active error
}
```

---

@GoswinvonBrederlow suggested throwing exceptions, this also works very well, even cleaner then `1 / 0` in my opinion:

```
consteval auto get_data(std::string_view search) {
    for (auto& data : data_set) {
        if (data.name == search) {
            return data.value;
        }
    }
    throw std::exception("fail");
}
consteval void check_data(std::string_view search) {
    for (auto& data : data_set) {
        if (data.name == search) {
            return;
        }
    }
    throw std::exception("fail");
}
int main() {
    constexpr auto foo = get_data("foo");
    constexpr auto foo2 = get_data("foo2"); //E3133 active error
    auto bar2 = get_data("foo2");  //E3133 active error

    check_data("foo");
    check_data("foo2"); //E3133 active error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there can be many elegant solutions but what I'd suggest is as simple as adding an unconditional return to the end of your function.

```
constexpr int get_data(std::string_view search) {
    for (auto& data : data_set) {
        if (data.name == search) {
            return data.value;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

See it running: https://godbolt.org/z/zKx7M3j8a

Comment: the problem with this is, that it's a valid statement. I want the statement `get_data("foo2")` to be invalid. This way I would have to check if the value returned is equal to `-1` and then produce an error, but the `get_data` function should already do that.

Comment: So... you want to have a compile-time check but not a compilation error? What exactly do you expect to happen if your search string is not in list?
You could have a `check_data()`, as suggested by @StackDanny, but returning a bool that you could check at run-time.
This way, you'd be able to have `constexpr` or `consteval` checks and only take actions on run time if it fails.
Did I get your intention right?
Updated: https://godbolt.org/z/Yza1n5zbv